# make kernel 5.9 error FAILED: load BTF from vmlinux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

make kernel 5.9

what can i do?

using ubuntu 20

this is error message in terminal

`FAILED: load BTF from vmlinux: Unknown error -2make: *** [Makefile:1162: vmlinux] Error 255`

Comment: It would be good, to transfer this question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/